# Does any language have a while-else flow structure?

Tags: coding-style

Consider this flow structure which I happen to use often:

```
if ( hasPosts() ) {
    while ( hasPosts() ) {
        displayNextPost();
    }
} else {
    displayNoPostsContent();
}
```

Are there any programming languages which have an optional `else` clause for `while`, which is to be run if the while loop is never entered? Thus, the code above would become:

```
while ( hasPosts() ) {
    displayNextPost();
} else {
    displayNoPostsContent();
}
```

I find it interesting that many languages have the `do-while` construct (run the while code once before checking the condition) yet I have never seen `while-else` addressed. There is precedent for running an N block of code based on what was run in N-1 block, such as the `try-catch` construct.

**I wasn't sure whether to post here or on programmers.SE. If this question is more appropriate there, then please move it. Thanks.**

Comment: Ooh I hope someone shows how to implement such a construct in Scala

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some languages have macro features to enable you to define such things. in *C*, *C++*, *Common Lisp* you could define such macros.

Comment: Thanks, this looks to be as close as we'll come to this feature.

Answer (score 6):

This is really esoteric. Standard Common Lisp does not provide it. But we find it in a library called [ITERATE](http://common-lisp.net/project/iterate/).

Common Lisp has extremely fancy control structures. There is a library called *ITERATE*, which is similar to Common Lisp's `LOOP` macro, but with even more features and more parentheses.

Example:

```
(iterate (while (has-posts-p))
  (display-next-post)
  (else (display-no-posts-content)))
```

It does exactly what you want. The *else* clause is only run once when the *while* clause was never true.

Example:

```
(defparameter *posts* '(1 2 3 4))

(defun has-posts-p ()
  *posts*)

(defun display-next-post ()
  (print (pop *posts*)))

(defun display-no-posts-content ()
  (write-line "no-posts"))

(defun test ()
  (iterate (while (has-posts-p))
    (display-next-post)
    (else (display-no-posts-content))))
```

There are some *posts*:

```
EXTENDED-CL 41 > *posts*
(1 2 3 4)

EXTENDED-CL 42 > (test)

1 
2 
3 
4 
NIL
```

There are no *posts*:

```
EXTENDED-CL 43 > *posts*
NIL

EXTENDED-CL 44 > (test)
no-posts
NIL
```

Answer (score 4):

Python has `else` clauses on `while` and `for`, but they only run if the loop is never broken out of with `break`, `return`, etc.

Comment: [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_loop_control.htm)
This is for python

Answer (score 0):

I am no particular fan of Common Lisp's LOOP macro, but it can do it with

(loop while (has-posts-p) do (display-next-post) finally (return (display-no-posts-content)))

No return necessary if you don't care about the value.

Comment: No, that's something different. The `FINALLY` clause is always executed. What is needed is a clause which runs only when the `LOOP` body has not run. `LOOP` has no such feature.